# Why does code in debugger work but not in actual execution

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am working on a neural net and I have a LinearTransform object. My issue exists in my backprop function.

I have sometimes a vector and a scalar, and in this case I want to do scalar multiplication and not change the dimensions of the vector.

Other times I will have a vector and a vector and what I want as a result is a matrix.

So I am using np.dot. However I need the dimensions to be valid for the dot product so I cast the inputs to matrices from arrays.

My code looks like this:

```
    tmp1 = np.matrix(zin)
    tmp2 = np.matrix(grad_output)

    pdb.set_trace()

    delt = np.dot( tmp2 , tmp1 )
```

Where this is dims:

```
(Pdb) tmp1.shape
(1, 3073)
(Pdb) tmp2.shape
(1, 1)
```

In debugger I run:

```
-> delt = np.dot( tmp2 , tmp1 )
(Pdb) np.dot(tmp2, tmp1)
matrix([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ..., -0.01216065,
         -0.03115987, -0.00775516]])
(Pdb)
```

Which is the intended result.

However when I continue execution I am given a value error:

```
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (3073,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (3073,3073)
```

What black magic is causing this line to no longer work?

As requested full traceback:

```
  File "myfile.py", line 255, in <module>
    lr, momentum, l2_penalty)
  File "myfile.py", line 177, in train
    siphon.append( lyr.backward(siphon[-1], p, lr, mtm, l2_p) )
  File "myfile.py", line 38, in backward
    delt = np.dot( tmp2 , tmp1 )
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (3073,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (3073,3073)
```

And I assume you want the function leading up to this:

```
 def backward( self, grad_output, zin,
    learning_rate=  0.1, momentum=0.1, l2_penalty=0.0 ):
    tmp1 = np.matrix(zin)
    tmp2 = np.matrix(grad_output)

    pdb.set_trace()

    delt = np.dot( tmp2 , tmp1 )
```

Which is identical to the code I've already posted but provides context.

Comment: Show the complete traceback (i.e. the complete error message).  It should show the line where the error occurs.  Have you transposed one of the arrays in the code?

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and run to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I've identified the issue. The error was on a later line where I use the output to do element-wise addition with another np.array of the wrong dimension. Apparently the error message was coming on the wrong line.